# Load png image from resources works wrong on jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm doing a simple activity with an image inside. I have my image on the drawable folder. It's a png. But when I show the preview o run the app on my emulator it shows like this:

[image]

This is the code:

```
@Composable
fun SplashBody() {
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(color = Color(0xFFF85B1A)),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
) {
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.dbz_logo_2), contentDescription = "")
}}
```

Comment: please add link to download your image. usually PNG images with transparent bg work fine to me

Comment: Looks like the image itself is not transparent.

Comment: I think, Image itself isn't transparent background.

Comment: I downloaded like 4 images from google and I had the same problem. 
https://www.google.com/search?q=dbz+logo+png&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinjrKd3bP0AhX9G7kGHStTCR0Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1792&bih=871&dpr=2#imgrc=hQJszP7NbJl6mM

Comment: Try this image https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20211126faxnRpyY